# Как телеграм боту получить доступ к сообщениям?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, telegram

Как боту Telegram получить доступ к сообщениям пользователя и делать рассылку?
Имеется несколько каналов и нужно, как только в каком-то из них появляются новые данные - тут же их сливать в другой канал, либо в бот.

Как такое делается на C#? (Лучше Asp.Net Core)

Comment: Вероятно крон который будет брать id последнего поста и сверять с последним слитым. Если больше то сливать

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы иметь доступ к сообщениям, публикуемым в канале, бот должен быть администратором канала. Поэтому вопрос этот **не программный**, а **организационный**.

Answer (score 0):

Такой функционал возможен только клиентом, до момента пока администратор канала не поймет, что сливается контент. 
на C# к сожелению не подскажу, но на Python вполне удобная библиотека.
на гите есть аналогичные под шарп. [например](http://www.sochix.ru/how-to-send-messages-to-telegram-from-c/)